# LLVM: generate runtime error

Tags: c++, llvm

How can I generate a runtime error based on a condition?

I have a language which supports ranged integer types. For example, one type is integers from 0 to 99, another type would be integers from -100 to -20, and so on. The types are defined by the user. The range for each type is known at compile time.

I want to throw a runtime error if the user performs an arithmetic operation that results in an integer outside its defined range. How can I do that using the C++ API for LLVM?

Comment: Is it the runtime exception you're curious about, or how to insert the checks?

Comment: The runtime exception. I perform checks by using Compare Instructions (ICmpInst ) followed by a branch instruction with 2 defined blocks, 1 for error, 1 for normal behavior.

Comment: And, for further clarification, does this have to support *catching* these exceptions, or is acceptable in the domain to just error out?

Comment: No, I don't need that support. I only want to abort with an error, no try/catch involved.

Comment: Ok, so just calling into a C function which does: `printf("Invalid arithmetic operation"); exit(-1);` is too coarse, or you just need help building the call?

Comment: It's a good idea. I will do that. But does that mean that llvm does not 'natively' provide an instruction to exit the program?

Comment: That might be your real question -- I don't know; It seems to me that it's outside the purview of LLVM. A suggestion might be to look for `__builtin_exit()` or similar. Or just look and see how llvm compiles exit();

Answer (score 0):

This is in the domain of runtime libraries.  Typically the language provides a runtime library the compiler can rely on for more complex functionality like this.  In your case, the error path of the branch would lead to a call into the runtime library to some error function that takes some number of arguments.  The runtime library handles printing the error and terminating the application.  The runtime library can then be compiled by your compiler and linked to the user code.